# Integer field radio buttons doen't save

Tags: 6, entities

I have integer field with 3 radio button options. When I select one of the option try to save new content it doesn't save the integer value. Field is not required and options are like this:

```
car|Car
plane|Plane
boat|Boat
```

After saving node and going back to edit none of the radio buttons is selected. Not even the default N/A which should be automatically selected if nothing else is selected. Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an integer field and the key should be an integer.

Try

> 0|Car
>   1|Plane
>   2|Boat

Comment: Great, this did the trick!